# tsconfig: excluding node modules without an include

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, tsconfig

In an Angular project I have a single tsconfig file which doesn't `extend` any other tsconfig, nor does it have an `"include"` property. At the very bottom, however, we have the following:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fakeProperty1": true,
 },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

What is this `exclude` accomplishing?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), the default value for `include` is `**/*`, meaning all TS files. So the `exclude` with no `include` is including all TypeScript files from your current directory and all subdirectories, except those in `node_modules`.

Comment: But doesn't the exclude property have a default value of 'Node_Modules'? (technically on the ts documentation I see a default value of `node_modules,bower_compon` https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude, although I don't know what `bower_compon` is. But isn't this just doing the same as the default? So what's the point?

Comment: Yes, it is doing the same thing as the default. The full list of default excludes is `node_modules,bower_components,jspm_packages` but that's cut off by the styling on the docs site. So I suppose technically having an explicit exclude for node_modules might make the compiler a few milliseconds faster since it wouldn't have to check for those additional directories, but most likely someone just added it thinking it was necessary.